# Run jar with classpath parameters

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm probably missing something stupid but still.
I created a jar file with the following inner structure:

- folder1
- folder2
- META-INF
- resources

where folder1 and folder2 hold .class files and resources has txt and png files.
In my code i have the following line

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(txtFile)));
```

where `txtFile` is a string holding a file name that is located within the resource folder. (directly in the folder).
The problem is when i try to run the program from the command line.
This is the command i run.

```
java -cp externalJar.jar;myJar.jar;resources com.my.package.MyMainClass
```

The program runs and fine unit i get to the above code line where i get a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.my.package.MyMainClass.generateSomething(Unknown Source)
at com.my.package.MyMainClass.main
```

which i guess means that there is something wrong with my classpath - but i can't figure what...

**EDIT**
I'm using ant to compile and package my program to an executable jar.
This is my part of my `build.xml`:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${executable.jar}" basedir="${bin}">
        <zipfileset dir="${src}\resources" prefix="resources" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyMainClass" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="externalJar.jar" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

**EDIT - 2**
Because it's supposed to be an executable jar the value of the `txtFile` variable is hard coded (unless given as an argument) to be the file name inside the resources directory. So eventually, i would like to run this command:
`java -jar myJar.jar`
Unfortunately - this also results in the same manner (NullPointerException on the same line)

**EDIT - 3 (FOUND UN-ELEGANT SOLUTION)**
I found that if i concatenate to all the paths of files that are read by a class loader the prefix `"resources/"` then it works fine - but i find this to be un-elegant. Is there no way to add the resources folder to the classpath?

Comment: Don’t use `getSystemResourceAsStream`; your resource is not a *system resource*. Use `getResourceAsStream`; note that it should work when running from the file system (i.e. without a JAR) as well. So you should try to get it running before packaging into a JAR.

Comment: When i run it from eclipse, it runs ok (i changed the classpath of the project)..
I'll add the ant task that packages it to a jar... maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Don't ignore advice given, try with getResourceAsStream() and report the results.

Comment: I'm sorry that it may seem that i have ignored - I wasn't. i used `reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyMainClass.class.getResourceAsStream(txtFile)));` without any success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you only plan to access files that are within the same jar as your `MyMainclass`, you can call `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` on its class loader rather than `getSystemResource()` / `getSystemResourceAsStream()`.

```
public class MyMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = MyMainClass.class.getResourceAsStream(args[0]);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Second, you should pass the path to the file rather than passing the resources folder on the classpath:

```
java -cp externalJar.jar;myJar.jar com.my.package.MyMainClass "/resources/myTextFileInUtf8.txt"
```

Please also note that it is (almost) always a good idea to specify the encoding when creating an InputStreamReader, otherwise you rely on the JVM default encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - as suggested, i used `reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyMainClass.class.getResourceAsStream(txtFile)));` without success....

Comment: What is the value of `txtFile` at that point? It should be the path to your text file from the root of your jar file. Also, are you sure that your text file is correctly bundled into your jar file?

Comment: Regarding your Edit 3, no there is no way to add ´resources´ folder as a root to the classpath (it is already on the classpath under the ´resources´ path). So, your options are 1) pass the full path to your program "resources/mytextfile.txt", 2) prefixed the passed file with "/resources/" as you did or 3) move all your image and text files to the root of your jar.

Answer (score -1):

Well one thing is clear, `txtFile` variable would be a `null` or non existing path, as the NPE is originating from there.

OR

Another chance of problem would be the  invocation of  `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(txtFile)`

Inorder to make the proper loader access your resource, change it to

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(txtFile);
```

and use  the stream.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, your solution didn't work. In addition, i checked and the `txtFile` isn't null.