# Get resources in a Java/Gradle Project correctly

Tags: java, gradle

I have small java application to simulate some sort of transactions.

I have some static resources under `src/main/resources`, I use Gradle to build an executable fat jar with java plugin.

**Question:** *what is the best way to access the resources from the code?*

This is the way that I am trying to do it.

```
   ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
   URL url = loader.getResource(folder);
   String path = url.getPath();
```

- **Issue**, when I do `java - jar/build/libs/my.jar` from the root of application to execute it runs fine and finds resources correctly as the files are under `build\resources` folder.
- If I do it form different directory then it will take the relative path from that directory, hence it will not find the resources needed.

Some generic answer how to handle java resources correctly would be just great. To be able to execute jar from anywhere needed.

Basically, Is it a good idea to have a stand-alone jar which will contain resources and dependences at the same time. If yes how to do it correctly with Gradle?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018149/run-jar-with-classpath-parameters) help ?

Comment: Not really, as you see I am doing it in that way, but It will work only if you are in the root of the project when you are running the jar, the point is to have a stand-alone jar which will contain all dependencies and resources.

Comment: Use `getResourceAsStream`. You can't use the URL to access the file directly (at least, not through the file system).

Comment: getResource and getResourceAsStream they are pretty much work in the same way, however, I can not use the stream  as I use some library which is requires to give a path